# WordPress with audioplayer issue

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, soundmanager2, audio-player

I am using [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) to play audio file in WordPress. When I play audio in some browser like Firefox audio play in new window. I don't know why this is happing.

**My JS Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/index-rollup.js"></script>
```

**My HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="graphic">
  <li><a href="demo/_mp3/sample2.mp3" class="exclude">Rain</a></li>
  <li><a href="demo/_mp3/walking.mp3" class="exclude">Walking</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note: Getting issue after adding in WordPress.

[image]

I have also tried some other audio code but facing same issue.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Please, show the code you're using. Nice plugin, *me gusta!*

Comment: @b__ I have added my code.

Answer (score 1):

MP3 is [not fully supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility). You have to add an OGG version of the file. *If not mistaken*, I think the combination MP3 + OGG is enough to play in all devices/browsers.

From this [support thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/firefox_and_opera_html5_support):

> *If you want to use MP3 and OGG, for example, you can specify multiple URLs as an array to SM2:*

```
soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'foo',
    url: [
    '/path/to/some.ogg',
    '/path/to/some.mp3'
    ]
});
```

> *When the sound object is created, SM2 will take the first URL it can play and will use that for the sound object's URL property. See [SMSound.url](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-url) for more examples.*

In your example, you're using simple `<a>` elements. For greater control, I'd suggest using SM2 API.

Another possibility to **have only MP3** is to use Flash for viewing in Desktop, and use [**`wp_is_mobile()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) to serve the HTML5 version to mobile devices.

Comment: So I have to add both extension song.

Comment: Yes, you have to add two versions of the same song (it's a pain, but alas). Not sure how would we do it with `<a href="file.ext">`, that's why I suggest the API. I'll update the answer with another option.

Comment: One thing I tell you that at my working place I can't play song in Firefox but at home it's working. Any idea why Firefox behaving like this way.

Comment: Maybe that's why Firefox page I linked says *"MP3: Partial Support"*, looks like it depends on OS and Hardware.

Comment: Just for the records, would be nice if you added your hardware/OS specifications (home/work) to the Q.